# Identify Duplicated rows with Additional Column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, running-count

I have the following Dataframe:

```
   PplNum  RoomNum  Value
0       1        0    265
1       1       12    170
2       2        0    297
3       2       12     85
4       2        0     41
5       2       12    144
```

Generally the `PplNum` and `RoomNum` is generated like this, and it will always follow this format:

```py
for ppl in [1,2,2]:
    for room in [0, 12]:
        print(ppl, room)
```

```
1 0
1 12
2 0
2 12
2 0
2 12
```

But now what I would like to achieve is to mark those duplicates combinations of `PplNum` and `RoomNum` so that I can know which combinationss are the first occurrence, which are the second occurrence and so on... So the expected output Dataframe will be like this:

```py
    PplNum  RoomNum  Value  C
0       1        0    265  1
1       1       12    170  1
2       2        0    297  1
3       2       12     85  1
4       2        0     41  2
5       2       12    144  2
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can do it using [groupby()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) together with [cumcount()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) function:

```
In [102]: df['C'] = df.groupby(['PplNum','RoomNum']).cumcount() + 1

In [103]: df
Out[103]:
   PplNum  RoomNum  Value  C
0       1        0    265  1
1       1       12    170  1
2       2        0    297  1
3       2       12     85  1
4       2        0     41  2
5       2       12    144  2
```

Explanation:

```
In [101]: df.groupby(['PplNum','RoomNum']).cumcount() + 1
Out[101]:
0    1
1    1
2    1
3    1
4    2
5    2
dtype: int64
```

[Group-By examples](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html)

Comment: @MaxU, Thx for your asnwer, could you please explain how this works, `groupby` and `cumcount`?

Comment: @J.J.Marko, i've added links to the corresponding docs and to the `groupby` usage examples - i think it's a best explanation

Answer (score 1):

Here is my approach with a recursive function:

```
dfnondup = df.drop_duplicates(['PplNum', 'RoomNum'])


def rename_dup(df):
    def rename_dup(df, c, dfnew):
        dfnondup = df.drop_duplicates(['PplNum', 'RoomNum'])
        dfnondup['C'] = pd.Series([c] * len(dfnondup), index=dfnondup.index)
        dfnew = pd.concat([dfnew, dfnondup], axis=0)
        c += 1
        dfdup = df[df.duplicated(['PplNum', 'RoomNum'])]
        if dfdup.empty:
            return dfnew, c
        else:
            return rename_dup(dfdup, c, dfnew)

    return rename_dup(df, 1, pd.DataFrame())


dfnew, c = rename_dup(df)
```

The result `dfnew` will be

```
dfnew
Out[28]: 
   PplNum  RoomNum  Value  C
0       1        0    265  1
1       1       12    170  1
2       2        0    297  1
3       2       12     85  1
4       2        0     41  2
5       2       12    144  2
```

Comment: it looks so complicated. THX anyway!